# Get TOTP status from profile at Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, totp

How can I get TOTP status (set or not) for user profile using keycloak-js or API?

Tried:

```
keycloak.loadUserProfile().then(x => {...}) // there is no any info about totp
keycloak.loadUserInfo().then(x => {...}) // there is no any info about totp
```

Using Admin Rest API

```
GET "/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}"
```

There is no any info as well

Comment: Also it can be get from `/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}`  field totp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Admin REST API https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html:

```
GET /{realm}/users/{id}/credentials
```

If some object from the response array is `type: otp` (not only `type: password`), then you can be sure, that user has configured OTP.